# Por que Aplicación en Java guarda muy lento en Redis en Linux?

Tags: java, redis

Tengo una aplicación en Java que cuando guarda registros en Redis en Windows lo realiza de forma muy rápida, pero cuando me conecto con la misma aplicación pero a un Redis instalado en Linux el guardado lo realiza de una forma muy lenta.

Algún motivo por el cual el guardado en Linux sea demasiado lento ?

Answer (score -1):

Me pasa algo similar pero con Laravel, pudiste encontrar el motivo ? En mi caso tengo un docker con laradock y que incluye redis y anda bien, pero lo pongo en otro servidor sin docker todo instalado por separado y redis si bien funciona anda muy lento, para mi tiene que ser alguna configuración de REDIS porque el código es el mismo y el servidor es 4 veces mejor que el anterior

Comment: subiendo la propiedad maxclients que se encuentra en redis.conf  ayudo un poco pero no se logro resolver el problema de raíz, fue necesario instalar redis en la misma aplicación en la que corría el servicio que lo consumía, era como un tema de latencia